# Reading DisplayPort DDC/CI under linux using libdrm

Tags: linux

I'm trying to read the DDC information from my monitor which is attached to the DisplayPort link of my laptop.

Thus I'm looking up with `i2cdetect` and `i2cdump` but couldn't find it attached to the /dev/i2c bus.

My next step was to access through `libdrm`, and I already had set up an `drmModeConnector` but what comes next?

According to dekkard's answer i tried

```
sudo i2cdetect -l
i2c-0   i2c         i915 gmbus ssc                      I2C adapter
i2c-1   i2c         i915 gmbus vga                      I2C adapter
i2c-2   i2c         i915 gmbus panel                    I2C adapter
i2c-3   i2c         i915 gmbus dpc                      I2C adapter
i2c-4   i2c         i915 gmbus dpb                      I2C adapter
i2c-5   i2c         i915 gmbus dpd                      I2C adapter
i2c-6   i2c         DPDDC-B                             I2C adapter
i2c-7   smbus       SMBus I801 adapter at efa0          SMBus adapter
```

Which shows that the panel is attached to `i2c-2` and the DisplayPort to `i2c-6`. When I run `$ sudo get-edid -b 6` this leads to:

```
$ sudo get-edid -b 6
2 potential busses found: 2 6
Only trying 6 as per your request.
Bus 6 doesn't really have an EDID...
Couldn't find an accessible EDID on this computer.
Attempting to use the classical VBE interface

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call successful

    VBE version 300
    VBE string at 0x11100 "Intel(R) Sandybridge/Ivybridge Graphics Chipset Accelerated VGA BIOS"

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Report DDC capabilities

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call successful

    Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC1 transfers
    Monitor and video card combination supports DDC2 transfers
    0 seconds per 128 byte EDID block transfer
    Screen is not blanked during DDC transfer

Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Read EDID

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call failed

The EDID data should not be trusted as the VBE call failed
Looks like VBE was successful. Have a good day.
```

Although thanks for your help! @dekkard

Could anyone give me a hint about that or post some tutorials?

Thanks a lot and best regards,

Befedo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
sudo get-edid
```

> get-edid,  parse-edid  -  read-edid  tools  to  retrieve  and interpret
>          monitor specifications using the VESA VBE DDC protocol

For more info see here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/get-edid.1.html

**UPDATE:**

Try *ddccontrol*:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/ddccontrol/
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ddccontrol/

Also, this might lead you to a solution:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114359/how-to-get-edid-for-a-single-monitor

Comment: `apt install ddccontrol`

Comment: DDC/CI is great!

Answer (score 1):

With your same result from `get-edid`, the only function that displays the EDID for my HDMI monitor is `xrandr --verbose`.

Comment: `xrandr --verbose` parses EDID matrix data for my HDMI, but not for my DVI.